# Having trouble with custom loss function for YOLO using keras or tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function, yolo

I am trying to to define custom loss function for YOLO to detect presence of a single class object and locate its centre( kinda landmark detection) as learned from Andrew NG. Each grid of 49 grids outputs a vector(7*7*3) having depth of only 3 units. First channel indicates probability of object in that grid, and other two predicts coordinates of centre of my object for landmark detection.
I have lately been trying to get my head around tensor calculus to avoid a faulty loss function, but having trouble to improve accuracy.

I am just subtracting all three channels of `y_true` from `y_pred` but multiplying the result from 2nd and 3rd channel with 1st channel matrix of `y_true` as we don't want to account coordinates predicted in 2nd and 3rd channel if 1st channel is not predicting the presence of object itself.

```
def yol_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    shape = tf.shape( y_true[:, :, :, 0] )
    a=tf.ones([shape[0], shape[1], shape[2] ], tf.float32)
    loss = K.mean((K.square(tf.multiply(y_true[:, :, :, 0], a) - tf.multiply(y_pred[:, :, :, 0],a ))),axis=(1,2)) + 64*K.mean((K.square(tf.multiply(y_true[:, :, :, 0], y_true[:, :, :, 1]) - tf.multiply(y_true[:, :, :, 0],y_pred[:, :, :, 1]))),axis=(1,2)) + 64*K.mean((K.square(tf.multiply(y_true[:, :, :, 0], y_true[:, :, :, 2]) - tf.multiply(y_true[:, :, :, 0],y_pred[:, :, :, 2]))),axis=(1,2))
    return loss
```